# How to set up NAS-like off-site backup on a budget?

Tags: backup, nas

I am considering buying a NAS to back up all my data. To make sure the backup is secure against local hazards, I would like to place the NAS off-site.

Ideally I would like to replicate what I can do with services like Backblaze, but without relying on an external vendor (which can go out of business, data is not under my control etc.). I would like to do it on a budget not exceeding a NAS with 2x3TB storage in a RAID1 setup (~$500).

However I could not find any NAS which would support this cenario.

Other constraints:
- The off-site location does not have a public IP address (neither do I, but I can obtain one if it is needed).
- I would like the backup to act as a NAS - being able to access the drive as if it were a local drive (as opposed to going through a web interface/FTP)
- the device should be home-friendly (will be placed in an area where people live, so no loud servers)

Can you please provide recommendation how to accomplish this?

Comment: Dropbox? Google Drive... etc may be a better option. Also, if the device should be placed where people live, where do you plan on storing your off site NAS??

Comment: None of these are different from backblaze to me. No one can guarantee that dropbox will not go out of business in five years or that google will not stop google drive next year.

Comment: This question is not within the scope of Super User as it leans towards hardware recommendations which is opinion based and will make the answer only applicable now but possibly not in the future. We can help you with some of the other questions, but as the question is asked now, this is likely going to be closed. You may want to edit the question and refer to the button "Ask Question" to see what you can and cannot ask.

Comment: So, you're going to move the NAS offset to a data center where people live, and you'll have knowledge this data center will not go out of business in the next 5 years?

Comment: I am going to place a nas in my parents house. Even if I t were a datacenter the housed server would be mine. They could not take it away. Very different from dropbox - they can just decide they had enough and they have no obligation to keep your files. the motivation is to protect the backup from local disasters (a nas in my apartment gets lost along if anything disastrous happens to the original files)

Comment: @LPChip I am not interested in hw. I want to know how to set this up on IT systems configuration level.

Comment: This question will be closed I think, sorry. Since you appear to want a total bespoke solution, you may be best to pay some one to help you with it, or start learning how to do it... Static IP at your desintation and then just FTP it across. My QNAP Nas has this type of feature built in (can act as a webserver too)

Comment: @Dave I was looking for suggestions and options, not a full solution. Google search showed no one appears to be approaching this problem from the perspective I am, so I tried to get suggestions here. I know you are probably used to Dummies on this site but rest assured I am not one of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the tutorial you are looking for, but give an overview of a possible solution.

I would consider setting up a VPN connection between the NAS and your home network. This way the NAS becomes a part of your home network, and you can access yor NAS as if it is local - thus map it as a network drive. The data transfer will be secure.

Unfortunately setting up a VPN connection often is not trivial. I guess all major NAS vendors offers a VPN client. The tricky part will be the VPN server. Many routers includes VPN server in their firmware. If yours neither includes such firmware, or is supported by 3rd party firmware, ([ex. dd-wrt)](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) your budget may suffers an additional $100 for a new router.

Regarding IP addresses, my advice is to obtain a public IP address for your local router. It does not need to be fixed. By using a Dynamic DNS (DDNS) client - probably already existing in your router - the NAS can address the VPN server by a domain name.

Comment: thank you, setting up the NAS to VPN back to my network seems like a good idea